# How to get the follow user with details from GetStream following API

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

I have created users with GetStream (`using client.user(user.id).getOrCreate({})`;) and getting those users full details in the Feeds. Could I get the same User details in the **following** API too?.
currently, I get the

> user:ID as target_id

only.

```
"results": [
        {
            "feed_id": "timeline:d9fa73e8-9cd7-4ac1-aa4b-fe148971e1f0",
            "target_id": "user:6bb0fb62-ed9a-4966-b713-774f1d7aa3e5",
            "created_at": "2019-03-06T06:36:36.97424846Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-03-06T06:36:36.97424846Z"
        },
        {
            "feed_id": "timeline:d9fa73e8-9cd7-4ac1-aa4b-fe148971e1f0",
            "target_id": "user:admin",
            "created_at": "2019-03-05T13:49:13.52832166Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-03-05T13:49:13.52832166Z"
        }
    ]
```

Is there any chance to get the user full details in **following** and **followers** APIs too??

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do it, although we are aware of this limitation and we have this task in our backlog.

For now, the recommended approach is to request the user data from your own backend